# How to select one row before another one - from a two tables SQL?

Tags: java, sql, syntax-error, mariadb

The Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UNIQUEID,ID
FROM
(
  (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID
     FROM stackscontents
    WHERE BACKGROUND IS NOT NULL 
      AND TITLE IS NOT NULL 
      AND ID < ?
    ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 1)
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID
      FROM stackscontents 
      WHERE BACKGROUND IS NOT NULL
        AND TITLE IS NOT NULL
        AND ID > ?
      ORDER BY DATE ASC limit 1)
)
UNION ALL (
  (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID
     FROM sharedlinks 
    WHERE ID < ?
    ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 1)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID
     FROM sharedlinks
    WHERE ID > ? 
    ORDER BY DATE ASC limit 1)
) t
```

To be precise, I am trying to get a row before another row from 2 tables. But I am getting syntax error as below:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Every derived table must have its own alias

Below is the code where I am using the query:

```
if (NewDetails == null) {

        query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT UNIQUEID,ID FROM ((SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM stackscontents WHERE BACKGROUND IS NOT NULL AND TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ID < ? ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 1) UNION ALL (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM stackscontents WHERE BACKGROUND IS NOT NULL AND TITLE IS NOT NULL ID > ? ORDER BY DATE ASC limit 1)) UNION ALL "
        + "((SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM sharedlinks WHERE ID < ? ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 1) UNION ALL (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM sharedlinks WHERE ID > ? ORDER BY DATE ASC limit 1)) t ";

    try {
        DBConnect Database = new DBConnect();
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            con = Database.getcon();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query2);
            ps.setInt(1, minID);
            ps.setInt(2, minID);
            ps.setInt(3, minID);
            ps.setInt(4, minID);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                minID = rs.getInt(2);
                parts[i] = rs.getString(1);
                i--;
            }
        } finally {
            if (ps != null)
                ps.close();
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if (con != null)
                con.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                       
}
```

unfortunately it also does not return expected row - 1, but it returns 451 from stackscontents which is the first row. as below:

Stackscontents:

[stackscontents table rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ifNI.png)

sharedlinks:

[sharedlinks table rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHGIR.png)

Comment: You are missing `AND` instead use `TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ID > ?`

Comment: Yes, you are missing an `AND` before `ID > ?`. However, what are you trying to do? I'm not quite sure you are doing it right.

Comment: Please format query for human readability.

Comment: @Andreas, @TheImpaler, adding the `AND` worked but now i am getting `Every derived table must have its own alias` error :(

Comment: @Andreas I have update the query, hopefully now its human readable.

Comment: You can use `try-with-resources` syntax in place of `try-catch-finally` with `close` methods. Here is a link to an article at Oracle's Java tutorials on using [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: If you want the final result ordered, then you need an `ORDER BY` at the end.

Comment: @aaasdf - What is the initial value of `i`?  `4` would not be safe since the `DISTINCT` could lead to fewer than 4 rows.

Comment: @RickJames, I believe that's okay, I only need 1 row

Comment: @aaasdf - Then why not modify the SQL to deliver only one row?

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis are messing things up. Here is your code reformatted to show why:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT UNIQUEID,ID
 FROM (
        (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM stackscontents WHERE BACKGROUND IS NOT NULL AND TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ID < ? ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 1)
       UNION ALL
        (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM stackscontents WHERE BACKGROUND IS NOT NULL AND TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ID > ? ORDER BY DATE ASC limit 1)
      )
UNION ALL
      (
        (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM sharedlinks WHERE ID < ? ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 1)
       UNION ALL
        (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM sharedlinks WHERE ID > ? ORDER BY DATE ASC limit 1)
      ) t
```

No wonder the SQL parser goes "Huh?"

Your code should be:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT UNIQUEID,ID
 FROM (
        (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM stackscontents WHERE BACKGROUND IS NOT NULL AND TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ID < ? ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 1)
       UNION ALL
        (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM stackscontents WHERE BACKGROUND IS NOT NULL AND TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ID > ? ORDER BY DATE ASC limit 1)
       UNION ALL
        (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM sharedlinks WHERE ID < ? ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 1)
       UNION ALL
        (SELECT UNIQUEID, DATE, ID FROM sharedlinks WHERE ID > ? ORDER BY DATE ASC limit 1)
     ) t
```

Comment: that almost seems to work, but why am I getting ID `451`(from stackscontents) where the requested ID is (63-1)(available at sharedlinks)?

Comment: @aaasdf - Let's see the data -- in order to help you with 451, etc.

Comment: @RickJames attached the images in my question update, see if that helps :(

Comment: @aaasdf - `... AND TITLE IS NOT NULL ID > ? ...` looks like a syntax error.

Comment: @RickJames had that fixed, the only issue now is that it return row ID 451, rather than 1 row before.

Comment: @aaasdf Your code is looking for last row before *and* first row after, so why are you confused that `ID > 63` returns 452, assuming that record 452 is the first record after 63 where `BACKGROUND` and `TITLE` are both non-null? And remember that you're ordering by `DATE` only, not by `ID`, so if multiple records have the same date, it's arbitrary which one you'll get.